# PSCredental objects in Azure Functions apps? cannot connect to M365 web services

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-identity

System.Management.Automation.PSCredential appears to be missing in Azure Functions apps.

I need to query Exchange Online mailboxes for attribute "litigationHoldEnabled = $true" as part of a orchestration, to run daily.

I ran the following in debug in KUDU and it terminated the process: 
`$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell-liveid?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true" -Credential $credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection`

 my code works in PS locally on my PC. I added the ExO v2 module to the wwwroot of the functionapp. Got the following in red: 

Write-Host : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred
while setting character attributes for the console output buffer. Contact
Microsoft Customer Support Services.

Answer (score 0):

Write-Host : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred while setting character attributes for the console output buffer. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.

To resolve the above error, you can try either of the following ways:

1. Using the PowerShell Console of the Kudu site of an Azure App Service:

> ```
> Prevent the progress meter from trying to access the console mode
> $ProgressPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
> ```

2. Use Write-Output instead of Write-Host
   References: The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 0x6 occurred while getting the console mode and Executing PowerShell in Azure Web Job